# Why do I need to CAST() in query?

Tags: mysql, casting

probably, this is a well known questions, but I can't find answer in docs. 
If I run these queries:

```
SELECT @next := 2, @amount := 1;

SELECT @next := 0.2, @amount := 0.1, @result := @next - @amount;
```

I will get wrong @result = "0"

If I run the 2nd query once more, result will be correct.

If I use type casting in the 2nd query and run both queries again, result will be correct too. I.e.,

```
SELECT @next := 0.2, @amount := 0.1, @result := CAST(@next AS DECIMAL(2,2)) - @amount;
```

Why does it happen? What should I read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is you first set @next := 2, @amount = 1.
Which then makes @next and @amount of type int.
So when you assign @next := 0.2, @amount := 0.1 on this line @next takes on the value of zero and so does @amount.
But after this select runs @next changes type to decimal.
To see what's really happening try this

```
SELECT @next := 2, @amount := 1;

SELECT @next := 0.2, @amount := 0.1, @next, @amount, @result := @next - @amount;

SELECT @next,@amount;
```

so to not having to CAST, just set your first statement to

```
SELECT @next := 2.0, @amount := 1.0;
```

and everything will start as a decimal and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Ah, I understood - user variable keeps its starting type and I need to explicitly change it, if it doesn't meet the type of new assigned value! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The cast expression has similar semantics to the SQL CONVERT
>   expression. The cast expression is used to convert a value of one type
>   into a value of another type.

`DECIMAL` has two parts: `Precision` and `Scale`. So part of your query will look like this:

```
CAST(@next AS DECIMAL(2,2))
```

`Precision` represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values. 
`Scale`  represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

[Read More](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/)

Comment: Yes, I understand what type casting do. But why do I need it in my example?